# TDD, Resharper, Visual Studio 2015, are not multi projects friendly

Tags: visual-studio, ide, tdd, resharper

I have a C# solution with a project for my unit test (and several production logic projects). Every time I write a test first, I'd like the generated code to go to the right project.

For instance if I have a project named "BusinessLogicA" (assembly and namespace names alike) and I add a refernece to it in my unit test project, that inside some test class I have the following code.

```
using ThisNameSpaceExist = BusinessLogicA;
....

var instanceOfAlreadyExistingClass = new ThisNameSpaceExist.AlreadyExistingClass();
var instanceOfNewClass = new ThisNameSpaceExist.NewClass();
```

Where AlreadyExistingClass exists and NewClass doesn't, then whenever/however I try to autogenerate NewClass, it gets created inside the UnitTest project.

```
namespace UnitTest.BusinessLogicA {
    class NewClass {
```

It's important to note, all projects are withing the same solution and I reference the project (not the built dll), so everything should be set to have the class created at the right place (inside the right project).

Is there a way to enable/force this behaviour?

If not, any lead on how to deal with it the easiest way?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, how would Resharper/Visual Studio/RandomTool know where your generated class should go?  Ideally, your unit tests would have a namespace that is similar to the classes they test, such as:

```
namespace UnitTest.BusinessLogicA
namespace BusinessLogicA
```

And so be in a spot on disk that maps to these, like:

```
root\UnitTest\BusinessLogicA
root\BusinessLogicA
```

But there are hundreds of variations on this that I can think of that the tool would have to be smart enough to handle, or offer some configuration.  I don't think it's an impossible problem, but I don't know of any tool that can do this.

To alleviate this a bit though, I have a "finger macro" for classes that I auto-generate:

1. Put the cursor on the auto-generated class name (it's there as soon as you ask Resharper to create the class).
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> *(Open refactor context menu, select "Move to folder")*
3. In the dialog that comes up, remove the test-specific part of the path, which maps to the corresponding business-logic path of my solution.
4. Accept the dialog.

I can't get it much faster/easier than that, so of course I'd love a plugin that just moves it to the right spot automatically.